# Media query not functioning as expected

Tags: css, media-queries

I have some CSS

```
.fullscreen-bg {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -100;
}

.fullscreen-bg__video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
       -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .fullscreen-bg {
        background: url('../img/MichaelPR.jpg') center center / cover no-repeat;
    }

    .fullscreen-bg__video {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div className="fullscreen-bg"> 
    <video loop muted autoPlay className="fullscreen-bg__video"> 
        <source src={background} type="video/mp4" /> 
        <source src={background} type="video/ogg" /> 
        Your browser does not support the video tag. 
     </video> 
</div> 
<div> 
    <img className="logo" alt="Great State" src={logo} /> 
</div>
```

That I understand should have a background video only when the screen is larger than 767. The background video is always showing. So it leads me to believe that the media query that I have is not functioning. I have tried to set the default background to a color but still now luck. How can I show a background image only when the screen size is above a certain limit?

Comment: could you add your html code?

Comment: Here is the HTML
```
       <div className="fullscreen-bg">
            <video loop muted autoPlay className="fullscreen-bg__video">
                <source src={background} type="video/mp4" />
                 <source src={background} type="video/ogg" />
                Your browser does not support the video tag.
            </video>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img className="logo" alt="Great State" src={logo} />
        </div>
```

Comment: your html says className instead of class it should just be ```class="fullscreen-bg"```

Comment: @NicoShultz OP is using a JS framework of some sort, so `className` gets rendered into `class` in the HTML.

Comment: Ah okey that explains but when i put his code in a jsfiddle and change className to class it works as expected

Comment: @NicoShultz then we know something else is going on with the other code on OPs site.

Comment: Is this a React project, Then May be I can help.  @KevinBurton

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] (this almost certainly means removing anything React specific and providing plain HTML with URLs that actually resolve) using the live demo feature of the question editor.

Comment: Is this just me or does `<video>` simply not accept the `class` attribute???? (W10 Firefox). `className` is an error so it is ignored anyway....

Comment: @RenevanderLende It's just you. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Audio_and_video_delivery/Video_player_styling_basics

Comment: of course it's me, it's always me!

Comment: Sorry this is a React project. And the "HTML" that I posted was actually JSX.

Comment: Here is a codepen that exhibis the same behavior. Basically the video is always there despite the width. https://codepen.io/rkb/pen/abdaprJ

Answer (score 0):

*Replace your media tag like this*

```
@media all and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 767px) {...} 
or
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)  {...}
```

**And add this meta tag or replace with the current one with**

```
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
```

Comment: Still no luck all - https://codepen.io/rkb/pen/abdaprJ